# How can I download a file from WordPress upload folder from another website?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, download

I am trying to download a file with login authentication using WordPress database, I am using the below code to download file from WordPress upload folder. But unfortunately, I am unable to download the requested file and no error message. Can any one help me to fix this issue.

```
if (isset($_GET['downloadfile'])) {
    $posts_id = $_GET['downloadfile'];
    $sql_app = $auth_user->runQuery("
        SELECT DISTINCTROW AA.post_id, 
            BB.`meta_value` AS 'resume' 
        FROM `wp_postmeta` AS AA 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS BB ON AA.post_id = BB.post_id 
            AND BB.meta_key ='resume'
        WHERE AA.meta_key IN ('resume')
            AND AA.post_id=:posts_id
            GROUP BY AA.post_id
            ORDER BY AA.post_id DESC
    ");
    $sql_app->execute(array(":posts_id"=>$posts_id));
    $downRow=$sql_app->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $filepath = $downRow['resume'];
    // Process download
    if(file_exists($filepath)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
        flush(); 
        readfile($filepath);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking here; where does the 3rd-party site you mentioned in the title come into play here?

Comment: i hosted this code in one of my domain and trying to download files from WordPress domain.

Comment: Well what have you done to debug this so far then? Have you verified that the query worked and returned a file path as you expected? Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: I am getting expected file path with filename in $filepath.

Comment: And does file_exists actually return true for that?

Comment: file is available in the expected path. But if i copy and paste the path in the browser, WordPress automatically redirected to page not found.

Comment: Do you have a file system path here, or a URL? If it’s a URL, and gets redirected when you call it in the browser, then likely the same thing will happen when readfile tries to read the contents.

Comment: http://domain/wp-content/uploads/jobpost/2018/4787_RESUME-NAME.pdf is the full path with file, is printed in the $filepath and now i am getting does not exist. If check this in FTP the file is exists in that path.

Comment: That’s a URL, so if that doesn’t work inside your browser already, how do you expect it work work inside the script? Either see to it that this _is_ request-able via HTTP, or translate it into the according file system path.